# A circular reference was detected while serializing an object of type 'System.Web.HttpContext'

Tags: asp.net

I want to return a json object from an asp.net web service in this format `{"Part_ID":"2","Part_NAME":"\u0645\u0633\u062a\u0644\u0632\u0645\u0627 "}`

but I get the following error

> System.InvalidOperationException: A circular reference was detected
>   while serializing an object of type 'System.Web.HttpContext'.

Code is :

```
      public class Service : System.Web.Services.WebService
      {
        public string name;  
        public Service()
        {

        //Uncomment the following line if using designed components 
        //InitializeComponent(); 
        }

        [WebMethod(Description = "Your Description")]
        public string FunctionName()
        {
          var a = new Service { name = "tamzinho" };
          JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
          string retJSON = js.Serialize(a);
          return retJSON;
        }
      }
```

Comment: It is really the bad idea to try to serialize the service itself. I suppose you wanted to serialize some data object, which can be received from that service.

Answer (score 0):

```
var a = new Service { name = "tamzinho" };
...
string retJSON = js.Serialize(a);
```

This code is your problem:  the serialization will be attempted infinitely because you then try to serialize an instance of the same class, which will attempt to serialize another instance (and so on...)

**Separate your data into a separate object.**

eg:

```
public class MyServiceData {
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public string Description { get; set; }
}

public class Service : System.Web.Services.WebService
{
   public MyServiceData GetInfo(int partId) {
       ... data access code
       var result = new MyServiceData() { 
           Name = ...;
           Description = ...;
       };

      ... serialize result data to javascript
      return result;
   }
}
```